# Bash script string expansion

Tags: bash, curl, scripting

I am having an issue with the entering the following command in bash at the moment:

```
RESPONSE=`curl -k "$line" --cert=\"$certfile:$certpassfile\" --silent --write-out --head '%{http_code}\n'`
```

where `$line` is the url, `$certfile` is the path to the pem file, `$certpassfile` is the certificate password.

I am getting the following error:

> ++ curl -k url '--cert="/certpath:certpassword"' --silent --write-out --head '%{http_code}\n'
>
> curl: option --cert="/certpath:certpassword": is unknown

When i don't double the quotation marks around the certificate file and don't escape it, so the command looks like the below:

```
RESPONSE=`curl -k "$line" --cert="$certfile:$certpassfile" --silent --write-out --head '%{http_code}\n'`
```

I receive the same error but a different path:

> ++ curl -k url --cert=/certpath:certpassword --silent --write-out --head '%{http_code}\n' curl: option --cert=/certpath:certpassword: is unknown

Any idea how I can create the command at it should be which is:

```
curl -k url --cert="/certpath:certpassword" --silent --write-out --head '%{http_code}\n'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just should strip that equal sign between `--cert` and the value:

```
RESPONSE=$(curl -k "$line" --cert "$certfile:$certpassfile" \
                --silent --write-out --head '%{http_code}\n')
```