# Right string expansion in Bash (for shell script)

Tags: bash, shell, expansion

I'm experimenting a little bit with a shell script, which should run git commands for multiple repositories on the same level. This project structure might be a bad idea, but this is another story.

Everything works fine until I've run into this problem:

```
DETAIL="test test" && command="commit -m '${DETAIL}'" && echo $(git ${command})
# -> error: pathspec 'test'' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

I've also tried other opportunities like

```
DETAIL="test test" && command="commit -m ${DETAIL}" && echo $(git ${command})
DETAIL="test test" && command="commit -m $DETAIL" && echo $(git ${command})
```

All give the same result (see above). I've also scanned [these](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) [docs](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) about string expansion, but I don't have the problem, that the variables/strings might be null or undefined. The last `echo` is not the problem, you can also store the result of `$(git status)` in a variable and echo this one (my way in the script).

I know, there are [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791095/bash-script-string-expansion) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618736/bash-expansion-inside-shell-script), but I did not found a similar scenario yet, since I'm just dealing with simple and non-null strings, but with (too?) many quotes.

Interesting variant:

```
DETAIL="test test" && command="commit -m '${DETAIL}'" && echo $("git ${command}")
# -> git commit -m 'test test': command not found # WHAT?
```

Also interesting, just:

```
command="commit -m 'test'" && echo $(git ${command})
```

works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bash arrays with proper quoting...

```
DETAIL="test test" && command=(commit -m "$DETAIL") && git "${command[@]}"
```

To your code:

- `echo "$(command)"` is the same as `command` (ok, trailing empty newlines are removed)
- `"command blabla"` does not execute file `command` with the first argument `blabla`. It will execute a filename named exactly with space `command blabla`.
- Inside `$("git ${command}")` you want to execute a filename named `git commit -m 'test test'` (exactly, this is the whole filename name, with spaces, after `${command}` is expanded). As on you system there is no file named `git commit -m 'test test'` bash returns command not found.

Comment: Great, thanks. Now I'm struggling with pouring this array into a local function and getting it right there. Here _runCommand_ is my local function: `declare -a commandArray=("commit" "-m" "${DETAIL}");` - next line - `run_command $commandArray`. Then inside the function: `local actualCommand=$@` - then - `result=$(git ${actualCommand[@]})`?

Comment: `bash` doesn't have first-class array *values*. When you say something is an array, it just means that there is an attribute set on the *name* which allows you to using indexing. It's really a thin layer of syntactic sugar over a set of distinct variables.

Comment: If `arr=(1 "2 3" 4)`, then: `f "${arr[@]}"` is equal to `f 1 "2 3" 4`. But `f ${arr[@]}` is equal to `f 1 2 3 4`, ie. the `"` matter. Only `"${arr[@]}"` will be properly exapanded. Using `$arr` you will get only first element. You can inside a function `local actualCommand=("$@")`.